# How to install multiple appium version on the same machine?

Tags: appium, multiple-instances

For my daily work I've been using appium 1.4.16 and java_client 3.3.0

I would like to start and to look into the new appium version (currently 1.5.1 / 3.4.1)
Download the new jar and embed into my project it's not an issue, but I was wonder how do I download 2 different appium versions and how do I start the specific version I need  ?

I've tried to use "appium-version-manager" , I've installed 1.4.16 / 1.5.0 / 1.5.1 but from some reason I couldn't launch appium ver 1.50 and above while 1.4.16 version was launched without any issues...

Any advice would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: what commands are you using to run the latest version?

Comment: i hope you are not running both instances at the same time. also try running using `avm latest`

Comment: of course not. I've installed 3 versions , 1.4.16 /1.5.1/1.5.0, the first one is running and the others are not...

Comment: Can you please tell the details steps to install avm and switching between the avium versions for windows